# tr() for plural forms is not defined in QML

Tags: qt, qml, translation

I'm trying to use tr() for defining texts with plural/singular forms of nouns in QML. But Qt Creator says tr() is not defined. Before I used qsTr() and it worked for me. Could you please help me to find the reason? Thank you

Example:

```js
Text {
    property int minutesValue: calculateMinutesLeft()
    text: qsTr("%1 %2".arg(minutesValue).arg(minutesValue > 1 ? " minutes left": " minute left"))
}
```

Comment: did you read [Internationalization and Localization with Qt Quick](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html)? There is nothing about `tr()`. Why do you think that should work? You've probably confused it with [QObject::tr](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#tr).

Comment: I've just read your article but anyway didn't catch how to distinguish singular/plural in QML..

Comment: please provide an example, [mcve] to illustrate the issue. Actually I guess you can refer to Qt [plural rules](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html#handling-plurals) both with [inserting parameters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html#4-use-op-op-x-to-insert-parameters-into-a-string)

Comment: I updated my question with an example. All I want is to solve problem with singular/plural form of word "minute/minutes" in a more elegant way

Comment: If you will see at [qsTr](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#qsTr-method) function - the last parameter is exactly what you need.  In your case it should be something like this `qsTr("minute","",minutesValue) + " left"`. After parsing that you will see in QtLinguist several options for the "minute" string - a plural, singular etc. the right option will be selected by the `n` parameter you pass. The `disambiguation` parameter can also be used.

Comment: I tried these three ways:
text: qsTr("%n minute(s)", "0", minutesValue), 
text: qsTr("%n minute(s)", "0", minutesValue)
text: qsTr("%n minute(s)", "", minutesValue)
it didn't work for me

Comment: you get it wrong. you haven't add any translation. actually the `sourceText` parameter of the `qsTr` is a key of a phrase. in your case it should be maybe `text: qsTr("minute","",minutesValue) + " left"`. after parsing the project with `lupdate` you will get a translation file (*.ts). Then when open it with `QtLinguist` you will see 3 variants for each token - a singular, a plural etc. so for your token `minute` you have to add 3 variants - "minute", "minutes" etc. than you have to compile the *ts file you will get  *.qm file that is binary translation file that you need to load before qml.

Comment: I got it, thank you!